# Clear cache for website without browsingData permission

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm working on an add-on that needs to clear the cache for one website on install. Shift+reload click would also work. I'm currently using browsingData.remove and that works. The problem is my users are concerned about chrome asking for "read your browsing history". Is there any way to make the warning less scary or clear the cache without those permissions.

Comment: Have you tried to use the browsingData.removeCache function without setting the permission? In the documentation it says the API requires this permission, but I have found an extension doing what you want without the permission: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/clear-cache-shortcut/jnajhcakejgchhbjlchkfmdidgjefleg?hl=en

Comment: The extension linked by NoNickAvailable uses browsingData permission, but it doesn't show any warnings. Zusor's problem is the `"tabs"` permission.